# Given a certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$, how many triples of non-negative integers $(a,b,c)$ satisfy a+b+c = n?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Given a non-negative integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_n = \{ (a,b,c) \in \mathbb{N} \mid a+b+c = n \}$, I want to calculate $Card(A_n)$. I'm assuming $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

I didn't know how to start so I made a python script to know how many elements there are in $A_n$, and later, check if my hypothesis were true.

```
n = 50

exp = list(range(n)) # Number of elements counted by the computer
ind = list(range(n)) #Hypothesis n.2
induc = list(range(n)) #Hypothesis n.1

ind[0]=1 #Setting the number of elements of A_0 = {(0,0,0)}
induc[0]=1

for i in range(n):
    count = 0

    for a in range(i+1):
        for b in range(i+1):
            for c in range(i+1):
                if (a+b+c == i): count += 1

    exp[i] = count
    ind[i] = (i+1)*(i+2)*0.5
    if (i != 0): induc[i] = induc[i-1] + i + 1

    # print('In A_n, n=', i, ' there are', exp[i], 'elements.')

count = 0
for i in range(n):
    if (exp[i] != induc[i] or exp[i] != ind[i]):
        print('For ', i, 'is false:', exp[i], ', ', induc[i], ', ', ind[i]) #To know whats the problem
        count += 1
if (count == 0): print('Hypothesis confirmed.')
```

My first hypothesis was that

$$ |A_n| = |A_{n-1}| + n+1, $$

and my second hypothesis is a consequence of the first one,

$$ |A_n| = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}. $$

I have tried for n=50, n=100 and n=1000. The computer tells me my hypothesis are correct, but i don't know how to prove them. I've tried induction, but I'm stuck.

Comment: This is very well known as [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: Consider first $B_n=\{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{N} / a+b = n \}$. What is $|B_n|$? Then how can you express $|A_n|$ using $|B_n|$?

Comment: If you want to include $0$, you should say triples of nonnegative integers.

Comment: If you allow repeats, its $\operatorname{choose}(n+2,2)$.

Comment: In general, the number of $k$-tuples of nonnegative integers adding up to $n$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. This could be seen by imagining that you have $n$ objects and $k-1$ dividers dividing the objects into $k$ groups. A $0$ means that you start with a divider with nothing before it, or end with a divider with nothing after it, or have $2$ dividers with nothing between them.